# Length of a vector for which a certain condition is true

Tags: r

file:///Users/alexafiorante/Desktop/Cottrell%20Lab/RawDataTMA.nb.html

I have a data set and I need R to count the number of rows for which the condition is true, ie count the number of rows for which column "phenotype" is "CD8", and column "ExprPhenotype" is 0. How do I do this? I included an HTML file of what my code looks like.

Eventually I will hope to have the table look something like this:

CD8-0  CD8-4 etc.

5000    6000 (numbers are arbitrary)

Comment: You need to take a look at [logical indexing](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/logical-indexing.html) since this is basic simple R syntax question. All you need is a vector satisfying your logic as in `pos <- col 1 == A && col2 == B` and then use that vector  `pos` for indexing your original dataset, i.e. `df[pos, ]`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).